# consider the given code snippet and find its time complexity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, computer-science

Although it is a [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science)  [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity),still i am posting this because  this question wants us to solve a good sequence and series.

### Question

> consider the given code snippet and find its time complexity.

```
   Void fun(int n){

     int i=1;
     int s=i;

     while(s<n){
                ++i;
                s=s+i;
               }

      }
```

## My Approach

analysing the code snippet ,number of times while loop being executed gives the time complexity.while loop is executed by following the given sequence.

$$(1+2)+(1+2+3)+(1+2+3+4)...(1+2+3+4+....n)$$

$$=1 \times n +2 \times (n-1) + 3 \times (n-2) +....n \times 1 $$

but i am clueless to move forward.please help me out.

Comment: The time complexity is atmost $\sqrt{n}$ because at the step $2\sqrt{n}$ you will surpass $n$. But the complexity may be lower.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri is my series wrong ?

Comment: Since you write $s = s + i$, i guess so.

Answer (score 0):

As @ShervinSorouri allready pointed out, your sequence is wrong.

After the $j$-th iteration you will have
$$
s = 1+2+3+ \cdots + (j+1)
$$
which is the arithmetic series with the result
$$
s = \frac{(j+2)(j+1)}{2} \approx \tfrac{1}{2}j^2
$$
for large j. To surpass $n$ you'll need
$$
j \approx 2\sqrt{n}
$$
I guess this is the complexity you are looking for.